# Anyone ever used PHP's (unset) casting?

Tags: php

I just noticed PHP has an type casting to `(unset)`, and I'm wondering what it could possibly be used for. It doesn't even really unset the variable, it just casts it to NULL, which means that `(unset)$anything` should be exactly the same as simply writing `NULL`.

```
# Really unsetting the variable results in a notice when accessing it
nadav@shesek:~$ php -r '$foo = 123; unset($foo); echo $foo;'
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: foo in Command line code on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() Command line code:0

# (unset) just set it to NULL, and it doesn't result in a notice
nadav@shesek:~$ php -r '$foo = 123; $foo=(unset)$foo; echo $foo;'
```

Anyone ever used it for anything? I can't think of any possible usage for it...

**Added:**
Main idea of question is:
**What is reason to use `(unset)$smth` instead of just `NULL`?**

Comment: `(unset)` was [deprecated with PHP 7.2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration72.deprecated.php#migration72.deprecated.unset-cast) and [removed with PHP 8](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-8.0/UPGRADING#L33).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's really no point to using

```
$x = (unset)$y;
```

over

```
$x = NULL;
```

The `(unset)$y` always evaluates to null, and unlike calling `unset($y)`, the cast doesn't affect `$y` at all.

The only difference is that using the cast will still generate an "undefined variable" notice if  `$y` is not defined.

There's a [PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55164) about a related issue. The bug is actually about a (in my mind) misleading passage elsewhere in the documentation which says:

> Casting a variable to null will remove the variable and unset its value.

And that clearly isn't the case.

Comment: Good find that notice generation. For that prospect, it might actually be pretty useful in some places.

Comment: The notice behavior opens the door to, say, logging that a variable was undefined even though you don't care about its value. Off the top of my head I can't really come up with a use case for that ability, though. The only other thing I can think of is that it could be used as a sort of "shorthand" edit to replace a value with null but still have some notion in the code of what the value in that place used to be.

Answer (score 6):

I’d guess (knowing PHP and it’s notaribly... interesting choices for different things, I may be completely wrong) that it is so that the value does not need setting to a var. For exact reason to use it for a code, I can’t think of an example, but something like this:

```
$foo = bar((unset) baz());
```

There you want or need to have null as argument for bar and still needs to call `baz()` too. Syntax of function has changed and someone did a duck tape fix, like what seems to be hot with PHP.

So I’d say: no reason to use it in well-thought architecture; might be used for solutions that are so obscure that I’d vote against them in first place.

Comment: I have no idea why you would want to chain function calls this way if you always want to pass `null` to `bar` in the first place...

Answer (score 4):

As of PHP 8.0.X, `(unset) casting` is now removed and cannot be used.

Answer (score 1):

For example it can be used like this

```
function fallback()
{
    // some stuff here
    return 'zoo';
}

var_dump(false ? 'foo' : fallback()); // zoo
var_dump(false ? 'foo' : (unset) fallback()); // null
```

Even if `fallback()` returns "zoo" `(unset)` will clear that value.