# In PHP, what purpose does (unset) have?

Tags: php

No, I'm not referring to the unset() language construct, but the (unset) type caster. From the PHP manual:

> The casts allowed are:
>
> - (int), (integer) - cast to integer
> - (bool), (boolean) - cast to boolean
> - (float), (double), (real) - cast to float
> - (string) - cast to string
> - (array) - cast to array
> - (object) - cast to object
> - (unset) - cast to NULL (PHP 5)

URL: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Does anyone have any idea about this (or even used it in an actual project)?

Comment: Check this guy's comment out, seems like just another way to unset(): http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#89637

Comment: @Madmartigan: that guy is wrong. Let's wait for an answer from deceze . He explained it a little [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55164)

Comment: agreed with @meze, (unset)$var does not actually unset the variable $var

Comment: @Lepidosteus: Not sure I understand, running that guy's code and `var_dump(isset($var))` returned false for me. Example: http://codepad.org/nArGYuEe

Comment: @Madmartigan:  `isset` checks if a variable is defined and has a value. NULL is not value... That's why he looks at notices

Comment: @meze: I still don't understand: At least in PHP world, an undefined variable's type *and* value is `NULL`, there is no "undefined" type. What is the difference?

Comment: @Madmartigan: but a variable can be defined and have a value of `NULL`. `isset` will return false for both cases.

Comment: @Madmartigan: this is because isset() return true for variable which are equal to null, from the documentation "Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL". His code set the variable to null, but it does still exists in the local scope. This is not the same thing as unset($hello) which would remove the variable from the scope (as if it had never been defined). If you had used unset($hello), you would get NOTICEs from php about $hello not existing when you var_dump() over it.

Comment: @Lepidosteus: You should compile these comments into an answer. Comments can go overlooked and I think your explanation would be useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anyone ever used PHP's (unset) casting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081896/anyone-ever-used-phps-unset-casting)

Comment: @meze I have already written all I have to say about this topic in the linked bug report and here: http://kunststube.net/isset/ It simply is a rather nonsensical construct, IMO.

Comment: @Esailija I didn't do a thorough search on SO before posting this question. My bad.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't even know this was a thing, but it seems like the purpose is just completeness for available php primitives (NULL being one of them).  Note that this *casts* the data .. it does not do a write.

```
$x = 'foon';
$y = (unset)$x;
var_dump($x, $y) // 'foon', NULL
```

Note that `x` is not `null` in spite of the cast.

Near as I can tell, there's no reason to ever use `(unset)<anything>` as opposed to just writing `NULL`.  Perhaps someone else can come up with a better answer, though.

Comment: It will evaluate `<anything>`. `NULL` won't.

Answer (score 2):

I use `(unset)` casting to avoid creating ugly `if` `else` statements in situation if you need to validate and use many variables, but if one variable is considered *incorrect* and you do not want to check remaining.

For example, you have following code:

```
$variableone = "ffo";
$variabletwo = "obb";
$variablethree = "aar";

if(checkonefailed($variableone))
{
    outputsomething();
}
else
{
    dosomething($variableone)
    if(checktwofailed($variabletwo))
    {
        outputsomething();
    }
    else
    {
        dosomething($variabletwo)
        if(checkthreefailed($variablethree))
        {
            outputsomething();
        }
        else
        {
            dosomething($variablethree)
            //And so own
        }
    }
}
```

You can rewrite it like this:

```
$variableone = "ffo";
$variabletwo = "obb";
$variablethree = "aar";

if(checkonefailed($variableone))
{
    outputsomething();
}
//False or check
elseif((unset)(dosomething($variableone))||(checktwofailed($variabletwo)))
{
    outputsomething();
}
elseif((unset)(dosomething($variabletwo))||(checkthreefailed($variablethree)))
{
    outputsomething();
}
elseif((unset)(dosomething($variablethree))/*or next variable*/)
{
  //And so own
}
```

Idea taken from Go programming code

```
if variableone := "ffo"; checkonefailed(variableone) {
    outputsomething()
} else if dosomething(variableone); variabletwo := "obb"; checktwofailed(variabletwo) {
    outputsomething()
} else if dosomething(variabletwo); variablethree := "aar"; checkthreefailed(variablethree) {
    outputsomething()
} else dosomething(variablethree)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `(unset) cast` has now been deprecated in PHP 7.2.x. So, don't use it anymore.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.deprecated.php#migration72.deprecated.unset-cast

Comment: True. `(unset)` was [deprecated with PHP 7.2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration72.deprecated.php#migration72.deprecated.unset-cast) and [removed with PHP 8](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-8.0/UPGRADING#L33).

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is some future use-case where a class can define how cast operators work, e.g as with per `__toString()`. A class could potentially be marked non-nullable and hence casting to null would throw an exception. That would be fundamentally different from assigning NULL, although why on earth it's named `unset` is a mystery.

Comment: Why `unset`? I think that they want to have cast for every type, even for null. But there is problem with `(null)` because this is nothing else than `NULL` in brackets. So most likely they have to avoid unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose is to cast to NULL, like you already wrote in your question:

```
(unset) - cast to NULL (PHP 5)
```

So let's say you have a variable `$var` of which `isset($var)` is `TRUE`. You can then cast that variable to `NULL`:

```
/**
 * @param mixed $var anything
 */
function func($var)
{
    if (isset($var))
    {
        $var = (unset) $var;
    }
    # the rest of the code expects $var to be NULL
    ...
}
```

Sure,`$var = NULL` would do the same here, but w/o casting.

Comment: We all understand it. But the question is wt.. what is it for?

Comment: For cases someone might need it.

Comment: Like?  I really can't think up any case

Comment: From my experiences those cases are *very* rare, as most input is not needed to be `NULL` so normally nothing is casted to `NULL`.

Comment: But if input is needed to be `NULL`, then we can just pass `NULL` as  an argument...

Comment: It's not possible to typehint `NULL` for PHP functions, so this can only be done inside the function body.

Comment: @meze: as of today, there are no cases where this actually provides any functionality over $var = null, however I guess it could be useful when planning features that are not ready yet, like $my_optionnal_parameter_default_to_null = (unset)$some_input, so you know you are going to use that variable but as long as its not ready for primetime you leave your cast in place.

Comment: For one, `if (isset($var))` would be better written as `if ($var !== null)`, since the variable will *always* be *set*, since it's a function parameter. Secondly, if the variable is always supposed to be `null`, why make it a function parameter in the first place? Third, even if that somehow made sense, just initialize `$var = null` at the top of the function, it has exactly the same effect.

Comment: @deceze: No need to wonder that much, the example is highly artificial  just to create the very rare case where this cast could be used. You could write something similar with the `(string)` cast for example.

Comment: Well, exactly my point: it's practically impossible to come up with a *reasonable* use case for `(unset)`. :)

Comment: Exactly what I wrote earlier already. I can't imagine to use it or to have read it in other's code. But actually it's available in the language, so if someone needs it, there it is ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php):

> Example #2 Using (unset) casting
>
> (unset) casting is often confused with the unset() function. (unset)
>   casting serves only as a NULL-type cast, for completeness. It does not
>   alter the variable it's casting.

So, the way I read it is "All types are castable, `null` is a type so just for consistency we added a cast to `null`"